# quotient of monotonic transformation of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, monotone-functions

Let $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a monotonic function that is smooth. I am considering the quotient $\frac{g(f(x_1))}{g(f(x_2))}$ for some $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Is is it possible to express or bound this quotient using knowledge on $\frac{f(x_1)}{f(x_2)}$? My inspiration comes from Lipschitz functions in which we have the definition $|g(f(x_1)) - g(f(x_2))| \le K|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|$ for some constant $K$. Are similar expressions available for quotients?